# data sync azure, first synchronization large database

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I'm trying to sync a local flock of data to an azure database, however as I have a lot of data it's taking a long time to sync first. I have already put the data in my azure database through the migration program. Even so, when I do the first synchronization it takes all the data. How to make it sync only the changes.

scenario:

1. local database
2. azure database (copy of local bank 1)
3. azure do not synchronize all data on first synchronization

Comment: Is this one directional sync or bidirectional

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data Sync currently does not support this scenario. When two databases are put in the sync group, they will be synchronized until each row has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Data Sync won't know the two databases are identical until it compares the data row by row. It is a very costly process and may take a long time if you have large databases/tables. Our recommendation is to have data only on one side and keep the same table empty in the other databases. In this case, data sync will use bulk load during initialization and it is much faster than row by row comparison.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found a kludge way to skip the initial sync.

First setup and start the sync one time and wait for the provisioning to complete. Then stop the sync.

Then execute

```
update [YOURDB].[DataSync].[provision_marker_dss]
set [state] = 0
where object_id = object_id('YourSyncTable')
```

Then start the sync again. It will complete almost instantly.

Then execute

```
update [YOURDB].[DataSync].[provision_marker_dss]
set [state] = 1
where object_id = object_id('YourSyncTable')
```

And then you should be good to go.